# python 3.2-using dictionary to assign each letter in alphabet a numeric value&finding the sum of words in a .txt file based on their letter values

Tags: python, list, dictionary, type-conversion, python-3.2

in python 3.2 i'm trying to use dictionary to assign each letter in the alphabet a value.  the pattern is 'a'=1,'b'=2, 'c'=3…'z'=26. i have a file called words.txt and in this file there is a long list of words.  the words start with the capital letters, however, my values are only defined for lower case letters.
anyways, to each word i have to assign a value corresponding to the sum of the values of its letters,
when the word is converted into lower case.
i also know how i find out  how many words in the list have a total value that is an integer multiple of 137?
i'm also very confused as to how to get python to reference the .txt file.

any help is welcome! thank you!

this is the code i have so far:

```
d = {'a':1,'b':2,'c':3,'d':4,'e':5,'f':6,'g':7,'h':8,'i':9,'j':10,'k':11,'l':12,'m':13,'n':14,'o':15,'p':16,'q':17,'r':18,'s':19,'t':20,'u':21,'v':21,'w':23,'x':24,'y':25,'z':26}

find = open("words.txt")
[x.lower() for x in ["A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K","L","M","N","O","P","Q","R","S","T","U","V","W","X","Y","Z"]]
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z']


def num_multiple():  

  for line in find:
    if line.find("word % 137 == 0") == -1:
    return line
   else:
        word = line.strip()

print(num_multiple)
print(len(num_multiple))
```

Comment: A quick way is `d = dict(zip(string.ascii_lowercase, range(1, 27)))`

Comment: @jamylak This saves a lot of time!  However, Python tells me that "name string is not defined".  Am I supposed to replace something?  Thank you!!!

Comment: @jamylak This saves a lot of time! However, Python tells me that "name string is not defined". Am I supposed to replace something? Thank you!!!

Comment: @jamylak Do you by any chance know how to solve the problem with the code below?
Thank you so much! Does Python know to use my "d"? I copied the list I posted (now changed in the one line version) in the original comment right above the code you wrote, and Python keeps returning with "KeyError: '\n'" in <module> values.append(d[letter_lower]) What am I doing wrong? Should d be placed elsewhere?

Comment: I use this for generating that dictionary `d =dict(enumerate(string.ascii_lowercase,1))`

Answer (score 1):

Well I see a few problems here. First, you are using `find` to find the result of the literal string `"word % 137 == 0"` and not the result of the calculation.

Here is some stuff that will simplify your code:

```
values_of_words = [] # all the values for words

with open('words.txt') as the_file:
   for word in the_file:
       word = word.strip() # removes \n from the word
       values = [] # we will store letter values for each word
       for letter in word:
          # convert each letter to lowercase
          letter_lower = letter.lower()

          # find the score and add it to values
          values.append(d[letter_lower])

       # For each word, add up the values for each letter
       # and store them in the list
       values_of_words.append(sum(values))

count = 0
for value in values_of_words:
    if value % 137 == 0:
       count += 1

print("Number of words with values that are multiple of 137: {}".format(count))
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Does Python know to use my "d"? I copied the list I posted in the original comment right above the code you wrote, and Python keeps returning with "KeyError: '\n'" in <module>
    values.append(d[letter_lower])
What am I doing wrong?  Should d be placed elsewhere?

Comment: I just updated the code, but keep in mind this won't work if your file has blank lines. For that, you'll have to figure it out on your own :) For your `d`, see @jamylak's comment on how you can efficiently generate it. `d` needs to be defined before you use it, so somewhere near the `values_of_words = []` line, add the logic that sets up `d`.

Comment: Thanks again!  Luckily there are no blank lines and it runs smoothly.  But I think I described the question in the initial post incorrectly.
What I really want to know is:
How many words in the list have a total value that is an integer multiple number of 137?
We would have to first calculate all the values and then run them through the for value loop for count you posted above.
So my (last) Q would be - how do I make Python sum up the values of each word and then determine if it's a multiple or not.
Right now it gives an answer of 234202, which is a lot for a random # like 137.

Comment: I was hoping you would find the mistake on your own, but I updated the code anyway.

Comment: Thank you! I was able to spot it, but I don't think I would be able to fix it.  Thanks for the elaborate response too!

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using the ord() and chr() functions to get the ASCII values of the letters?

```
with open('words.txt')as word_file:
    high_score = 0
    for word in word_file:
        word = word.strip()
    value = 0
    for letter in word:
        value += ord(letter) % 97
    if value % 137 == 0:
        high_score += 1
    print('Number of words with values that are a multiple of 137 {}'.format(high_score))
```

I realise that this doesn't do anything different to your previous answer, but it may be a little less memory expensive if your dictionary is very large. Also, being able to convert characters to ASCII values and back can enable you to do some really cool things, especially in cryptography.